# several open connection in rabbit with different java client version number

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, java-8, amazon-elb, spring-amqp

I have a rabbitmq cluster setup in AWS. The 2 machines are ha-all, mirrored queued and they are behind an ELB. The queue name hips.preprod.queue has a springamqp consumer. The springamqp version is 3.3.4.

The consumer connects to the ELB and not the hosts directly. When the consumer connects to the rabbit cluster a single connection is created. But after sometime I see more connections in rabbit on the same IP but on a different socket. The weird part is that the some clients under the Connection tab indicates that the version is 3.2.4 and other clients 3.3.4. I also checked the classpath of my consumer and I cannot find any 3.2.4 amqp jar. I am at a total loss as to how is it possible to have same client with different version. Has anyone experienced anything similar to this.

Below is the data from Connections tab

```
Network     Overview
Name                Protocol    Client  Node    From client     To client   Timeout     Channels    Virtual host    User name   State
10.161.2.178:27238  AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.3.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit2     17B/s(37kB total)   8B/s(24kB total)    1s  1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.178:27312  AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.2.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit2     1B/s(2.4kB total)   1B/s(1.2kB total)   25s     1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.178:27711  AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.3.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit2     17B/s(20kB total)   9B/s(10kB total)    1s  1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.178:28833  AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.2.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit1     1B/s(2.8kB total)   0B/s(1.4kB total)   25s     1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.178:29093  AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.2.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit1     0B/s(2.5kB total)   0B/s(1.2kB total)   25s     1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.178:29692  AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.3.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit1     16B/s(15kB total)   9B/s(7.9kB total)   1s  3   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.92:10032   AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.2.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit2     1B/s(1.7kB total)   0B/s(857B total)    25s     1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.92:56573   AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.3.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit1     17B/s(40kB total)   8B/s(21kB total)    1s  4   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.92:56703   AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.2.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit1     1B/s(1.7kB total)   0B/s(1.1kB total)   25s     1   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.92:9352    AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.3.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit2     17B/s(46kB total)   9B/s(29kB total)    1s  5   /INFOPUSH   
running
10.161.2.92:9506    AMQP 0-9-1  RabbitMQ / Java3.2.4    rabbit@infopush-rabbit2     1B/s(2.5kB total)   0B/s(1.2kB total)   25s     1   /INFOPUSH   
running
```

Thanks
-Parshu

Comment: This is very strange. I will just try to make sure that the libraries are up to date on all the apps using rabbit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not updating this post. I found out that another app had a connection leak which was using rabbit 3.2.4. Because rabbit is behind an ELB it was hard to track down the faulty application.

This issue is fixed now.

Thanks
-Parshu